# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was developing on my dev machine using Homestead. I committed both my `composer.lock` and `composer.json`. During this branch, I added `Hashid` and `LaravelDebugBar` to composer for development purposes. Everything worked fine on the development machine.

Once I pulled from master to my production machine, and ran `composer update`, and I get the following error:

[image]

When I type in `php artisan migrate` or `composer update`, I get the following error:

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/schedulizer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider' not found
```

I tried `composer clear-compiled`, `composer dump-autoload` tried manually requiring the `Hashid` package, and removing the offending lines in `config/app.php` and running composer update

I checked the service provider, and it is in my `config/app.php`..

Comment: Is the `Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider` class in your project folder somewhere? `grep -R "Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider" ./`

Comment: The grep seems to return no results, but I can definitely find it in `config/app.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running `composer update`, run `composer install` on the production machine instead; this will bypass the pre-update hooks that Laravel runs.

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/composer-update-on-deployment/replies/113869)

If they were dev requirements, then you can conditionally add them to your service providers list by adding them to your AppServiceProvider like such:

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

public function register()
{
    /* ... */

    if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
        // $this->app->register('');
    } else {
        $this->app->register('Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider');
    }
}
```

[Source](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/conditionally-loading-service-providers-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Oh my God I think this is it.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I mistook `composer upgrade` for `composer install`. Lesson learned. Thank you so much.

Comment: I may mistake, but I guess after install, you still can get the error when running `php artisan` for example

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin If they were dev requirements, then those wouldn't be normally installed. I've updated my answer to show how to conditionally add entries to the service providers list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if `Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider` exists. Also, double check all letter (it's always better to copy-paste namespace from documentation). Then try to run this command:

`composer dumpauto`

If it will not help, run this command:

`composer dumpauto -o`

Comment: Hi there. I tried all the things you mentioned, and made sure that the provider exists, but no luck.

Comment: Try to delete composer.lock in the root and run command with -o again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `php artisan config:clear` then I ran `composer update` and `composer install` but I got the same error message.

in my case, the problem was in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`
So I deleted the file manually and mission accomplished.